# Two postgresql server with same configuration, different performance

Tags: postgresql

I got two identical servers, in both is installed postgresql server version 9.0.4 with the same configuration. If I launch a .sql file that performs about 5k inserts, on the first one it takes a couple of seconds, on the second one it takes 1 minute and 30 seconds.

If I set synchronous_commit, speed dramatically reduces (as expected), and the performances of the two servers are comparable. But if I set synchronous_commit to on, on one server the insert script execution time increases of less than one second, on the other one it increases too much, as I said in the first period.

Any idea about this difference in performances? Am I missing some configuration?

**Update**: tried a simple disk test: `time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=8k count=200000 && sync"`

fast server output:

```
1638400000 bytes (1.6 GB) copied, 1.73537 seconds, 944 MB/s

real    0m32.009s
user    0m0.018s
sys 0m2.298s
```

slow server output:

```
1638400000 bytes (1.6 GB) copied, 4.85727 s, 337 MB/s

real    0m35.045s
user    0m0.019s
sys 0m2.221s
```

Common features (both servers):

```
SATA, RAID1, controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SATA AHCI Controller, distribution: linux centOS. mount -v output:
/dev/md2 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/md1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
```

fast server: kernel 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5 #1 SMP

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.1 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            3906     4209029     2102562   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         4209030     4739174      265072+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3         4739175  1465144064   730202445   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

slow server: kernel 2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 715404 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006ffc4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     4194303     2096128   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         4194304     5242879      524288   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3         5242880  1465147391   729952256   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

Could it be useful to address the performance issue?

Comment: Are you sure the servers' CPUs are identical?

Comment: Both servers have same hardware configuration and disk layout as well?

Comment: both yes. if needed, I can post the output of lspci / hdparm commands

Comment: Please run your `time` command multiple times (10 times for example). Also try it in single user mode — so any other process won't interact with disk during execution. Do you get similar results every time?

Comment: Are your drives SSDs, SATA, SAS, in RAID, which RAID, what kind of controller, which distribution, is it updated, which kernel version, are drive barriers enabled (`mount -v`), are your partitions 4k block aligned `fdisk -l -u=sectors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your slow server with newer kernel has working barriers. This is good, as otherwise you can loose data in case of a power failure. But it is of course slower than running with write cache enabled and without barriers, aka *running with scissors*.

You can check if barriers are enabled using `mount -v` — search for `barrier=1` in output. You can disable barriers for your filesystem (`mount -o remount,barrier=0 /`) to speed up, but then you risk data corruption.

Try to do your 5k inserts in one transaction — Postgres won't have to write to disk on every row inserted. The theoretical limit for number of transactions per second wound be comparable to disk rotational speed (7200rpm disk ≈ 7200/60 tps = 120 tps) as a disk can only write to a sector once per rotation.

Comment: 2 seconds against 1m33s? Can working barriers make a difference so huge? I know, a single transaction would be faster, but still I want to investigate on this difference of performance.

In fact, I performed the same 5k insert test on a third (virtual) server with kernel 2.6.32 (the same of the slow one), it run in a bunch of seconds. How can I check if these barriers are enabled, and in case try to disable these barriers, at least for test purposes?

Comment: @lorenzo: I've updated my answer to address your doubts. Yes — it can be 2s vs 90s. With no barriers — update 5k times small amount of data in disk cache. With barriers — wait 5k times for this data to be written to physical, rotating disk platter in this particular place.

Comment: mount -v output on slow server:
`/dev/md2 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/md1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)`

I can't see anything related to barrier..

Comment: @lorenzo: I can not find how to check if barriers are enabled on software RAID. They're enabled by default in CentOS6/RHEL6 and a [warning is written on boot to /var/log/messages about them being disabled](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel6/rhel_6_storage_admin/rhel_6_storage_writebarrieronoff.html). There's a tool in source Postgres distribution, `pg_test_fsync` (`test_fsync` in older Postgres), that benchmarks number of operations per second. If it is very high (for example 1000 of ops/sec) then there must be some kind of cache. If it's not backed by a battery then it is dangerous.

Comment: pg_test_fsync is very high (~3000 ops/sec or so) on the fast server, while is very slow (~50 ops/sec) on the slow server. how would I know if there is a battery backup? In each case, would it be nice to know where to act to enable / disable that kind of cache, which I cannot manage to identify.

Comment: On CentOS 5 the only way to disable dangerous cache on software RAID is to disable disk cache completely (`hdparm -W 0 /dev/sda` on boot). On CentOS 6 barriers are enabled by default and you can disable them with `barrier=0`. Battery backed controllers are expensive ($600+) so you would probably know if you had one.

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds like in the "fast" server there is a write cache enbled for the harddisk(s), whereas in the slow server the harddisk(s) are really writing the data when PG writes it (by calling fsync)

Comment: according to hdparm -i, both boxes' drive(s) have write cache enabled. is there something else that I should check?